# What type of objects are the DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, dom

Are DOM objects regular Javascript objects?  If not, what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the DOM objects are reguler Javascript objects? if not, what are they?

No, they're "host objects". They don't necessarily play by all the same rules as native JavaScript objects.

They're in some sense objects, but they're added by the host environment and are not part of the ECMAScript specification.

For example, I don't believe there's anything that requires them to accept expando properties. Or in the case of functions, I don't know that they're required to have an accessible and extendable `prototype` property.

Also functions may or may not have the typical methods of `Function.prototype`, like `.call()` and `.apply()`.

The rules are simply much looser than those of objects defined by the ECMAScript specification, so you can't necessarily rely on the same behavior in all cases.

Comment: To the people upvoting the comment above, I already elaborated quite a while ago. I understand that a 3 word comment is easier to read than several sentences... but come on.

Answer (score 3):

They are of type [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLElement)

Comment: Not all DOM objects are of type HTMLElement. Only HTMLElements are.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity: Then what are they?

Comment: [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) springs to mind as one example.

Comment: There are text nodes, attribute objects, and comment nodes for starters. Also, it depends on how far reaching "DOM objects" is intended in the question. There are several other objects in the environment that are not part of ECMAScript. Like `window.alert` or `window.setTimeout` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are:

```
> typeof document.body
"object"
> document.body instanceof Object
true
```

Comment: Um, (almost) everything in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: This demonstrates that it is indeed an object (but little else).

Comment: I think by "regular" object, he meant "plain object" (`{}`).  `HTMLElement`s aren't plain objects.  `$.isPlainObject(document.body) === false`.

Comment: The are very obviously not "plain" objects, they come with lots of methods and data attached.

Comment: So, therefore they are not "regular Javascript objects".

Comment: plain and regular are different things

Comment: The time has come where jQuery tells us which constructs are objects and which not!

Comment: Then what does he mean by "regular" object, or is that not the correct term?

Comment: I was assuming "Something that acts like any other JavaScript object". If that interpretation is wrong, then it makes more sense for the OP to clarify the question then for us to debate what they might have meant.

Comment: In IE8, `document.body instanceof Object` returns `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a description of the Documnet Object Model (DOM) from the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model):

> The Document Object Model is an API for HTML and XML documents. It
>   provides a structural representation of the document, enabling you to
>   modify its content and visual presentation. Essentially, it connects
>   web pages to scripts or programming languages.
>
> All of the properties, methods, and events available to the web
>   developer for manipulating and creating web pages are organized into
>   objects (e.g., the document object that represents the document
>   itself, the table object that represents a HTML table elements, and so
>   forth). Those objects are accessible via scripting languages in most
>   recent web browsers.
>
> The DOM is most often used in conjunction with JavaScript. That is,
>   the code is written in JavaScript, but it uses the DOM to access the
>   web page and its elements. However, the DOM was designed to be
>   independent of any particular programming language, making the
>   structural representation of the document available from a single,
>   consistent API. Though we focus on JavaScript throughout this site,
>   implementations of the DOM can be built for any language.
>
> The World Wide Web Consortium establishes a standard for the DOM,
>   called the W3C DOM. It should, now that the most important browsers
>   correctly implement it, enable powerful cross-browser applications.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is an API , so a set of predefined "objects" attached to the window "namespace".
It can be HTMLElements but not only and they are not part of the javascript core.
So there is the javascript core and the DOM , and you can have other APIS.